# Does anyone know how tumblr's homepage transitions from page to page?

Tags: javascript, html, transition, smoothing

When you go to http://www.tumblr.com/ and click on log in at the top it smoothly transitions without flickering like other webpages these days. What technology does tumblr use to achieve this? HTML5, how so?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually the same page; they simply use the HTML5 history api (`pushState()`) to modify the URL in the address bar.

See http://html5demos.com/history for a simple demo and http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html for details and a how-to.

Comment: actually the 1.5Mb page O_o (loads entire website?)

Comment: I don't see a 1.5MB site behind any of the links here.

Comment: @ThiefMaster,  tumblr.com (the OP's link)

Comment: `Size: 2,58 KB (2.647 bytes)` - by the way, why does this fscking website turn into french just because I'm connection from France? It should actually care about `accept-language` http headers instead of looking at the IP geolocation...

Comment: @ThiefMaster, empty your cache :)

Comment: Why would that change anything? The displayed size is the size of the HTML document, not the transferred size.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, heh, probably it either confused by my IP or... Got an en-us variant here. My point was - it doesnt allow to follow "sign in" link, but do DOM mutations instead.